# Python DataFrame Column to Key and Value

Tags: python

I am not sure if column to key value will bring my data to the desired output or not.

I simply have a Python Dataframe as the below image

[image: INPUT]

I need to output the data in this format below image :

[image: OUTPUT]

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Can you post the python dataframe? makes it easier to try to find a solution rather than rewriting it.

Comment: Hi Moenad, i am not sure how to attach the data. I have the csv copied below, hope this helps:    Customer_ID,Biscuits_Ord,Biscuits_Del,Biscuits_Ret,Soda_Ord,Soda_Del,Soda_Ret
ABC,7,7,32,10,10,10
XYZ,35,35,0,23,23,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert this wide dataset to long format by first creating a MultiIndex using [split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [stacking](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [flattening](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) the multilevel indices.

Example code can be:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID' : ['ABC', 'XYZ'],
                    'Biscuits_Ord': [7,7],
                    'Biscuits_Del': [32, 10],
                    'Soda_Ord': [7,7],
                    'Soda_Del': [32, 10]})
df_test.index = df_test['Customer_ID']
del df_test['Customer_ID']

df_test.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_test.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple).map(reversed).map(tuple))
df_new = df_test.stack()
df_new.index.set_names('Product', level=1, inplace=True)
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: you rock , thanks a million, i really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: just one more question : what if i have some products with 2 underscore   ,   for example "Biscuit_Plain_Ord".  How can i include this in the above code please

Comment: Can you try str.rsplit('_', 1) instead of str.split('_')?

Comment: I tried it again it worked, i am sorry. Thanks again